# Get Links into Array

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have been trying to pull all the links out of a certain div into an array and use them elsewhere on the page. It's for the software MyBB:

```
<div class="pm_alert" id="pm_notice">
    <div class="float_right"><a href="private.php?action=dismiss_notice&amp;my_post_key=d668d58abafb0f4ec8ab4c902e4eb460" title="Dismiss this notice" onclick="return MyBB.dismissPMNotice()"><img src="images/aesthetic/dismiss_notice.gif" alt="Dismiss this notice" title="[x]" /></a></div>
    <div><strong>You have one unread private message</strong> from <a href="http://localhost/mybb/member.php?action=profile&amp;uid=2">test account</a> titled <a href="private.php?action=read&amp;pmid=13" style="font-weight: bold;">take this</a></div>
</div>
```

The links are generated through the system though, same as the names. So I'd like to pull all 3 of them out of there so I can customize the message without having to edit .lang files. This is the code I'm using now but it isn't working, alert is giving me undefined:

```
var link_split = [];
var link_split = $('.pm_link > a').map(function(){
    return this;
}).toArray();
alert(link_split['']);
```

Comment: What kind of array do you need to get? Array of DOM elements, array of jQuery objects, or array of inner text?

Comment: I need the whole element. I just realized my code doesn't return the whole thing like I wanted (<a href="">stuff</a> instead of just the href). Any ideas? :x

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the error is in thomething like

```
.pm_link > a
```

It should be

```
.pm_alert a
```

Try the

```
alert($('.pm_link > a').length)
```

Comment: Yep, just a typo on my part, thanks for the help. This is the code that ended up working:  

var link_split = $('.pm_alert a').map(function(){
        return this;
    }).toArray();
    alert(link_split['0']);

Comment: Why not to use `var link_split = $('.pm_alert a').get();`?